# "Asked" box bleeds into feed link

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Browsing to the bottom of [this page](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging) shows the "asked" box over the top of the feed link:

[image]

Tested in Google Chrome 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.